# Querying data based on the date - Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I want to display search results queried based on the condition where the from_date is today or upwards and also the to_date is up until today if that exists in the range.

My query is as follows :

```
SELECT *
FROM device b LEFT OUTER JOIN device_model a
    ON (b.`model_ID`=a.`model_ID`)
LEFT JOIN sub_product_area c
    ON (b.sub_Product_Area_ID = c.sub_Product_Area_ID)
LEFT JOIN borrow_device d
    ON (b.device_ID = d.device_ID AND (from_Date >= CURDATE() or CURDATE() <= to_date))
WHERE (a.`name`LIKE '%galaxy%') OR (a.platform LIKE 'galaxy%') OR
    (a.`type`LIKE '%galaxy%') OR (a.`OS`LIKE '%galaxy%') OR (d.username LIKE '%galaxy%') OR
    (c.`sub_Product_Area_name` LIKE '%galaxy%')
ORDER BY d.`transaction_Mode` DESC
```

My table structures are here:

[image]

The problem is it doesn't display results where the next clause after 'OR' gets true. Is there anything wrong with my query?

Comment: Your date condition doesn't make sense to me.  Could you demonstrate, by way of example, which types of records you want to retain based on their `from_date` and `to_date` ?

Comment: I want to display results where the from_date >= today OR to_date >= today. That is where the from_date is today or upward date OR to_date is today or in a future date. Hope this  is clear enough

Comment: Why would a from_date ever be null? And consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result.

Answer (score 0):

you put your condition in the join clause and you should get it out to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM device b LEFT OUTER JOIN device_model a
    ON (b.`model_ID`=a.`model_ID`)
LEFT JOIN sub_product_area c
    ON (b.sub_Product_Area_ID = c.sub_Product_Area_ID)
LEFT JOIN borrow_device d
    ON b.device_ID = d.device_ID 
WHERE (from_Date >= CURDATE() or CURDATE() <= to_date) AND ((a.`name`LIKE '%galaxy%') OR (a.platform LIKE 'galaxy%') OR
    (a.`type`LIKE '%galaxy%') OR (a.`OS`LIKE '%galaxy%') OR (d.username LIKE '%galaxy%') OR
    (c.`sub_Product_Area_name` LIKE '%galaxy%'))
ORDER BY d.`transaction_Mode` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to **correct this one** and try:

```
LEFT JOIN borrow_device d
    ON (b.device_ID = d.device_ID AND (from_Date >= CURDATE() or CURDATE() <= to_date))
```

**TO:**

```
LEFT JOIN borrow_device d
    ON (b.device_ID = d.device_ID AND (from_Date >= CURDATE() or to_date >= CURDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I have seen the condition for a.platform as "(a.platform LIKE 'galaxy%')" and not as "(a.platform LIKE '**%**galaxy%')" (i.e. '%' for 'galaxy%' part like other parts of where clause.)

2) If 'to_date' could be null, try adding a condition to check for nulls in join condition i.e. ( or `to_date` is null or ...)

3) Consider wrap field names with character " ` " .

4) Have you tried your query without where clauses?

Hope it work for you.